# Thread safety of a queue backed by ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class DedupingQueue<E> implements QueueWrapper<E> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DedupingQueue.class);

private final Map<E, Future<E>> itemsBeingWorkedOn = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final AsyncWorker<E> asyncWorker; //contains async method backed by a thread pool

public DedupingQueue(AsyncWorker<E> asyncWorker) {
    this.asyncWorker = asyncWorker;
}

@Override
public Future<E> submit(E e) {
    if (!itemsBeingWorkedOn.containsKey(e)) {
        itemsBeingWorkedOn.put(e, asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(e, this));
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("Rejected [{}] as it's already being worked on", e);
    }
    return itemsBeingWorkedOn.get(e);
}

@Override
public void complete(E e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Completed [{}]", e);
    itemsBeingWorkedOn.remove(e);
}

@Override
public void rejectAndRetry(E e) {
    itemsBeingWorkedOn.putIfAbsent(e, asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(e, this));
}

}
```

I am having some difficulty reasoning the thread safeness of the above code.

I reckon `complete` and `rejectAndretry` are completely thread-safe as the map is thread safe. But what about `submit`, given that `AsyncWorker` per se is not thread safe? Also, how can I make it thread safe in the most efficient way, without using `synchronized` **(using built in guarantees of ConcurrentHashMap)**?

Comment: Thread safety depends on what behavior you expect. If overwriting an existing key and/or not returning that same value is ok, then `submit()` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `compute()` method, which function takes the key, the current value or `null` if there's no current mapping, and returns the value to keep in the map, or remove it if `null` is returned.

```
@Override
public Future<E> submit(E e) {
    return itemsBeingWorkedOn.compute(e, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
            return asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(k, this);
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Rejected [{}] as it's already being worked on", k);
            return v;
        }
    });
}
```

---

Note that your queue is not ordered.  If you ever need FIFO or LIFO order, you should use a more suitable data structure, such as `LinkedHashMap` with `synchronized` statements.

Comment: If there weren't a logging line, this could be shortened to `return itemsBeingWorkedOn.computeIfAbsent(e, (k) -> { return asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(k, this); });`.

Answer (score 2):

`submit()` isn't thread safe because your check-then-act sequence isn't atomic. State for a particular key for one thread can be changed by other thread right after check and before invocation. Use an atomic method from ConcurrentHashMap (most likely `computeIfAbsent()`) to fix this issue.

```
if (!itemsBeingWorkedOn.containsKey(e)) {
    itemsBeingWorkedOn.put(e, asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(e, this));
}
```

If `AsyncWorker` isn't thread safe what whole class isn't thread safe as well. But it's hard to reason about it without `AsyncWorker` source code.

Comment: Partial credit. You're correct about the sequence not being atomic, but `putIfAbsent` isn't suitable because it would still always execute `asyncWorker.executeWorkAsync(e, this)`, but not necessarily put it in the map. Therefore `compute()` or `computeIfAbsent()` is required. Thread-safeness of `AsyncWorker` does not affect the whole class, in particular not the `complete` and `rejectAndRetry` (as is also indicated in the question).

Comment: Thanks, you are right, `putIfAbsent` won't work here and `computeIfAbsent` should be used. I had doubts so wrote "an atomic method from". Will edit my answer. Regarding the second part i've never seen reasoning about thread safety of a particular class method, also it's clear from the class logic that other methods don't make sense without `submit()`. Plus `rejectAndRetry()` also uses `AsyncWorker`.

Comment: Well, `complete()` is "logically" thread-safe due to `remove()` being thread-safe. You could get a duplicate logging line though, so strictly speaking it's not thread-safe. Looking at `rejectAndRetry` more closely, I can't really understand what its supposed purpose is.

Comment: Plus with non-thread-safe `submit()` it's possible to complete and retry another thread task with the same key instead for original one.

Comment: Well yes, `submit()` isn't thread-safe. That was established.